# Why %n in scanf returning 0 when reading a string from console

Tags: c, string, scanf

I tried to write a program which takes a line from user (console) until a comma, full stop or newline character is encountered and tell how many characters read following the specific pattern.

The string is read correctly but the count is not accurate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char s[100];


    // The following line should read a string until (. or , or new-line in encountered) 
    // and %n should tell me the no of characters it read until that point
    scanf("%[^.,\n]s%n", s, &n);


    // The String in okay
    printf("%s\n", s);

    // But count of characters read is 0
    printf("%d\n",n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your format string is looking for a literal `s` in the input.

Comment: This seems to be an extremely common mistake -- where do people get the idea that `[...]` is a modifier to `%s` rather than a format operator of its own?

Comment: Thank you @user3121023 and Barmar

Comment: Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/lVWKhgnfSwkipzP7 showing @user3121023 was right.

Comment: This is why you *always* check `scanf()`'s return value.

Comment: @Barmar One of life's true mysteries, that one.

Comment: @Barmar, perhaps that happens when people start with `%s`, decide they want `%[`, but forget to delete the `s`? (Or mis-hit delete)

Comment: @TobySpeight I think it's more than just an editing issue, I'd put money on a conceptual problem.

Comment: @Shawn, while I fully agree that checking `scanf()` is necessary, it might not be sufficient to diagnose here: `%n` conversion doesn't increment the assignment count.  So it should return `1` as expected.

Comment: @Barmar, I think you're right.  My suggestion was Devil's Advocate at best...

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm sure they're thinking 's` is for strings, but I want to filter the string. It's too common to be a typo (although I believe that the `=` for `==` mistake *is* just typos or sloppiness, I've even done it myself).

Comment: @TobySpeight "So it should return 1 as expected" -->  `scanf("%[^.,\n]....` does not return 1 when first character is of `.,\n`.  Return value check still prudent.

Comment: @chux, yes - I said necessary, but not sufficient to diagnose the extra `s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5 problems:

The `"s"` in `"%[^.,\n]s%n"` stops scanning as there can be no `'s'` read after `%[^.,\n]`.  `%[^.,\n]` would have read in all `'s'`.  Thus the later `"%n"` never occurred and the `n` that was later printed, a `0`, was bad code - printing the uninitialized `n` - which could have been any `int` or a trap.

Scan lacks a width limit.  Bad things happen after the 99th character.

With `scanf("%[^.,\n]s%n", s, &n);`, scanning will saving nothing in `s` if the first character is a `.,\n`.  Later printing of `s` is bad as `s[]` is uninitialized.

Code fails to check the return value of `scanf()`.

`scanf()` does not certainly read a *line* as directed with "write a program which takes a line from user" - it stops short using `scanf()`.
C Std Lib defines a line as below, so code should attempt to read the entire line.

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character.

---

`scanf()` alternative

```
int n = 0;
char s[100];
s[0] = '\0';

int cnt == scanf("%99[^.,\n]%n", s, &n);
if (cnt == EOF) puts("Nothing was read");
else printf("%s\n", s);
```

---

Better alternative

I'd recommend using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`: *takes a line from user*.

```
char s[100];
if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
  size_t n = strcspn(s, ".,\n");   // offset of string that does not have .,\n
  s[n] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", s);
  printf("%zu\n", n);
}
```

Note: Lines longer than about 100 need additional code.